# sequence diagram - multiple participants in the same column

Tags: sequence-diagram

I'm trying to create a sequence diagram (on https://sequencediagram.org/) for an algorithm where a long-lived participant calls into several short-lived participants. I can describe this behavior using the `destroy` keyword like so:

```
LongLived->*ShortLived1:request
LongLived<--ShortLived1:response
destroy ShortLived1

LongLived->*ShortLived2:request
LongLived<--ShortLived2:response
destroy ShortLived2

LongLived->*ShortLived3:request
LongLived<--ShortLived3:response
destroy ShortLived3
```

[image]

However, as you can see, the diagram gets wide very fast. Is there an way to move the temporary participants in the same column?